# Нет доступа к базе данных MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Я установил MS SQL Server 2008 R2 с стандартными настройками.

Дополнительно установил - Среда SQL Server Management Studio

- в свойствах сервера есть разрешение на удаленное соединение с этим сервером
- проверка подлинности SQL Server и Windows
- сервер перезапущен

В Sql Server Configuration Manager, в протоколах для серверов TCP/IP

- TCP/IP  включено
- активны и включены
- адреса (родной и 127.0.0.1) включены и активны
- в IPAll стоит порт 1433
- браузер SQL Server запущен, используется встроенная учетная запись СЕТЕВАЯ служба
- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) запущен, используется встроенная учетная запись СЕТЕВАЯ служба

Службы перезапущены. Остальные вкладки не настраивал.

Доступ к БД в сети отсутствует. Почему?  Прошу помощи!

Comment: Возможно, Вы неправильно прописываете имя сервера при подключении, попробуйте: `.\SQLEXPRESS`, `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS` или `имя_комп\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот вопрос не касается программирования, и относится, скорее уж, к области системного администрирования.

Comment: Локально подключается?

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию в SQL Server Express запрещено подключение по протоколу TCP - его нужно включить, тогда инстанс будет доступен по сети.

Comment: В вопросах записано TCP/IP включены

Answer (score 1):

Хм, еще банально фаерволл блокировать.